# Mapping ids from one array to other in js

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to map all the vins from vins array to rawResponse array based on ewr_fr_id.

Below is my code:

```
const rawResponse=[ { ewr_fr_id: '303',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null },
  { ewr_fr_id: '303',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null },
  { ewr_fr_id: '302',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null },
  { ewr_fr_id: '302',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null } ];

const fieldReportIds=[ '303', '303', '302', '302' ];

const vins=[ { vin: '2FMPK3J84FBB73425', ewr_fr_id: 303 },
  { vin: 'USELESS', ewr_fr_id: 302 },
  { vin: 'USELESS2', ewr_fr_id: 302 },
  { vin: 'VIN5801', ewr_fr_id: 303 } ];
```

This is want I am trying:

```
  for (const row in rawResponse) {
    getVins = await db.select(context.dbClient, q.getVinsQuery, [rawResponse[row].ewr_fr_id]);
    if (vins.length > 0 ) {
    rawResponse[row].vins =  _.map(rawResponse, vins, 'ewr_fr_id');
  }
  else 
  {
    rawResponse[row].vins = []; // if there is no vins then add vins: [] to the response
  }
}
```

My expected result is:

```
   rawResponse=[ { ewr_fr_id: '303',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null,
    vins:['VIN5801', '2FMPK3J84FBB73425']},
  { ewr_fr_id: '303',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null,
    vins:['VIN5801', '2FMPK3J84FBB73425']},
  { ewr_fr_id: '302',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null,
    vins:['USELESS', 'USELESS2']},
  { ewr_fr_id: '302',
    ewr_id: 102,
    yrq: '182',
    file_sequence: '1',
    fr_sequence: '102-182-1',
    manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter',
    report_category_cd: 'L',
    report_category_description: 'LightVehicle',
    date_qtr: '2018Q2',
    file_version: 1,
    file_type_cd: 'F',
    application_cd: 'S',
    application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL',
    file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF',
    model_or_platform: 'VOLTA',
    model_year: '2016',
    is_attachment: 'false',
    cmpt_01: '10',
    cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain',
    cmpt_02: null,
    cmpt_descr_02: null,
    cmpt_03: null,
    cmpt_descr_03: null,
    cmpt_04: null,
    cmpt_descr_04: null,
    cmpt_05: null,
    cmpt_descr_05: null,
    vins:['USELESS', 'USELESS2'] } ];
```

Basically I am trying to modify rawResponse array to add vins array if the ewr_fr_id is same as that in vins arrays, if there is no match then add an empty array (vins:[])

Answer (score 2):

```
rawResponse.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  vins: vins
    .filter(vin => vin.ewr_fr_id.toString() === item.ewr_fr_id.toString())
    .map(vin => vin.vin)
}))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a map function on rawRequest variable to start mapping each item and then run a for loop on vins to find the vins to be added.

```
const res = rawResponse.map(item => {
    let myVins = [];
    vins.forEach(vin => {
        if(vin.ewr_fr_id===Number(item.ewr_fr_id)){
            myVins.push(vin.vin);
        }
    });
    item.vins = myVins;
    return item;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `forEach` and `reduce` here:

```
rawResponse.forEach(response => {
  response.vins = vins.reduce((vinsArray, vin) => {
    if (+vin.ewr_fr_id === +response.ewr_fr_id) {
      vinsArray.push(vin.vin);
    }
    return vinsArray;
  }, []);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to transform each item in `rawResponse`. Filter `vins` by `ewr_fr_id` using [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). And use `map()` on the filtered results to only return `vin`.

```js
const rawResponse = [{ ewr_fr_id: '303', ewr_id: 102, yrq: '182', file_sequence: '1', fr_sequence: '102-182-1', manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter', report_category_cd: 'L', report_category_description: 'LightVehicle', date_qtr: '2018Q2', file_version: 1, file_type_cd: 'F', application_cd: 'S', application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL', file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF', ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF', model_or_platform: 'VOLTA', model_year: '2016', is_attachment: 'false', cmpt_01: '10', cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain', cmpt_02: null, cmpt_descr_02: null, cmpt_03: null, cmpt_descr_03: null, cmpt_04: null, cmpt_descr_04: null, cmpt_05: null, cmpt_descr_05: null }, { ewr_fr_id: '303', ewr_id: 102, yrq: '182', file_sequence: '1', fr_sequence: '102-182-1', manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter', report_category_cd: 'L', report_category_description: 'LightVehicle', date_qtr: '2018Q2', file_version: 1, file_type_cd: 'F', application_cd: 'S', application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL', file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF', ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06573.PDF', model_or_platform: 'VOLTA', model_year: '2016', is_attachment: 'false', cmpt_01: '10', cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain', cmpt_02: null, cmpt_descr_02: null, cmpt_03: null, cmpt_descr_03: null, cmpt_04: null, cmpt_descr_04: null, cmpt_05: null, cmpt_descr_05: null }, { ewr_fr_id: '302', ewr_id: 102, yrq: '182', file_sequence: '1', fr_sequence: '102-182-1', manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter', report_category_cd: 'L', report_category_description: 'LightVehicle', date_qtr: '2018Q2', file_version: 1, file_type_cd: 'F', application_cd: 'S', application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL', file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF', ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF', model_or_platform: 'VOLTA', model_year: '2016', is_attachment: 'false', cmpt_01: '10', cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain', cmpt_02: null, cmpt_descr_02: null, cmpt_03: null, cmpt_descr_03: null, cmpt_04: null, cmpt_descr_04: null, cmpt_05: null, cmpt_descr_05: null }, { ewr_fr_id: '302', ewr_id: 102, yrq: '182', file_sequence: '1', fr_sequence: '102-182-1', manufacturer_name: 'Teryerter', report_category_cd: 'L', report_category_description: 'LightVehicle', date_qtr: '2018Q2', file_version: 1, file_type_cd: 'F', application_cd: 'S', application_description: 'SINGLE MODEL', file_name: 'SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF', ifs_document_id: '000003L041001FP-SFNLIBERTY4X4-0404-10-06572.PDF', model_or_platform: 'VOLTA', model_year: '2016', is_attachment: 'false', cmpt_01: '10', cmpt_descr_01: 'PowerTrain', cmpt_02: null, cmpt_descr_02: null, cmpt_03: null, cmpt_descr_03: null, cmpt_04: null, cmpt_descr_04: null, cmpt_05: null, cmpt_descr_05: null } ]; 
const vins = [{ vin: '2FMPK3J84FBB73425', ewr_fr_id: 303 }, { vin: 'USELESS', ewr_fr_id: 302 }, { vin: 'USELESS2', ewr_fr_id: 302 }, { vin: 'VIN5801', ewr_fr_id: 303 } ]; 

var result = rawResponse.map(item => {
  return { ...item,
    "vins": vins.filter(obj => obj.ewr_fr_id == item.ewr_fr_id).map(value => value.vin)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```